# Custom metric in keras with three parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, metrics

Hi everyone I'm building a deepNN using keras for forecasting time series, to be more specific I'm using a Conv1D so inputs are tensors with this kind of shape:

```
[samples, window_size, 1]
input_2  = Input(shape=(window_size, 1),name= "input_CNN")
```

My problem is that I'd like to have a custom metric that needs to recieve 3 parameters instead of the 2 standar `y_pred` and `y_true`. This because my metric needs to be safely computed as it does not rely on divisions with values that could be equal to zero (e.g. as done in percentage errors when  = 0).The complete formula of my metric is showed below:
[image]

How can I pass the  y_true_N and have a metric function like that?

```
def rmsse(y_true, y_pred, y_true_N):  
   
    N = len(y_true)
    numerator   = K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred))
    denominator = K.mean(K.square(y_true_N[1:N]-y_true_N[0:N-1]))
    return K.sqrt(numerator/denominator)
```

where the  `y_true_N` correspond to all the target values in the training while `y_true` and `y_pred` correspond to the target in the validation.
I hope I've been clear, if anyone has an example can please show me how to get it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that your denominator is a fixed quantity defined as you reported, I think there is no problem to define the third input in your loss function outside

here a code example:

```
def rmsse(y_true, y_pred):  

    numerator   = K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred))
    denominator = K.mean(K.square(y_true_N[1:N]-y_true_N[0:N-1]))
    return K.sqrt(numerator/denominator)

N = 1900
X = np.random.uniform(0,100, (N+100, 30)).astype('float32')
y = np.random.uniform(0,100, N+100).astype('float32')
y_true_N = y[:N].astype('float32')


inp = Input((30))
x = Dense(50)(inp)
x = Dense(1)(x)
model = Model(inp, x)
model.compile('adam', loss=rmsse)

model.fit(X[:N], y[:N], epochs=3, validation_data=(X[N:], y[N:]))
```

Comment: Let me know if there are some problems